# SQL error with sqlite in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

i have a hopefully simple Problem with an SQL-command

Code:

```
c.execute("SELECT MAX(pic_num) FROM Pictures WHERE id = "+str(user_id))
```

pic_num is a column in the database and user_id is an Integer in the database

I thought everything would be right but i get this
Error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

this Information doesn't help me at all

Comment: @PM77-1 http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You should print the constructed query string as it is fed to execute(). Maybe user_id isn't what you expect.

Comment: Just to add, string concatenation when executing SQL queries is _BAD_ and leaves you wide open for SQL injection. Check this page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html. Most drivers allow you to pass args for string replacement which will sanitize first and prevent said SQL injection.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - Based on OP question, I do not believe he's ready to deal with SQL Injection.

Comment: I think the docs suggest this should be something like: `c.execute("SELECT MAX(pic_num) FROM Pictures WHERE id = ?", str(user_id))`

Comment: But in the dB the id is an integer.. do i have to use single quotes even in this case?

Comment: @user8072518 PM77-1's "solution" is the worst possible solution. Don't do that, read the doc for the sqlite3 module and the two answers below (and Stev's comment). Use placeholders and your db-api connector will take care of sanitizing, escaping etc.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks to python's db-api, everyone is ready to deal with SQL injections in python: just use your db-api connector's placeholders instead of error-prone string formatting or concatenation. It's not only safer, but also way simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use python's db-api is to [use placeholders in your SQL query](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) and pass query values along, ie:

```
c.execute("SELECT MAX(pic_num) FROM Pictures WHERE id=?", [user_id,])
```

Note that this might not necessarily solve your problem but since you didn't post the schema nor the `user_id` value we can't try & reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should python sqlite module's substitution instead like so:

```
c.execute("SELECT MAX(pic_num) FROM Pictures WHERE id = ?", (user_id, ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the fast answers!

```
c.execute("SELECT MAX(pic_num) FROM Pictures WHERE id = ?", (str(user_id), ))
```

this finally worked :)

I already have written some libs which should handle SQL-injection (they test the Input for quotes but you're right im very new with SQL :D)

Comment: Escaping the strings is worse than using place holders. The place holders don’t parse what they’re given as sql at all, it’s a single item.